# Accessing data from connected tables in View of Entity Framework Core MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am building an MVC app using Entity Framework Core and having trouble accessing what I want from my views. I have 3 tables: Product, ProductImage, Image. ProductImage has a ProductId and an ImageId as the link between the Product and Image tables. I have added my models (in simplified form) below.

My problem is that the following in my cshtml (with a model of Product) causes an error as Image is null. Can anyone tell if this is a problem with my model, my controller, or something else? Thanks.

From .cshtml:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item.ProductImages.FirstOrDefault().Image.FileId.ToString();
}
```

From my Controller:

```
// GET: Products
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Products
            .Include(pi => pi.ProductImages)
            .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
    }
```

My Models;

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // ID (Primary key)
    public string Name { get; set; } // Name
    // Reverse navigation

    public virtual ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; } 

    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; } // FK_Product_Brand_BrandId

    public Product()
    {
        ProductImages = new List<ProductImage>();
    }
}

public class ProductImage
{
    public int ProductImageId { get; set; } // ProductImageID (Primary key)
    public int ImageId { get; set; } // ImageID
    public int ProductId { get; set; } // ProductID
   
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; } // FK_ProductImage_Image_ImageId

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; } // FK_ProductImage_Product_ProductId
}

public class Image
{
    public int ImageId { get; set; } // ImageID (Primary key)

    public string Caption { get; set; } // Caption
    public virtual ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; } // ProductImage.FK_ProductImage_Image_ImageId

    public Image()
    {
        ProductImages = new List<ProductImage>();
    }
}
```

This is what gets returned in the View:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expected behavior. `FirstOrDefault` may return null.

Rewrite your query:

```cs
// GET: Products
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Products
        .Include(pi => pi.ProductImages.Take(1))
        .ThenInclude(pi => pi.Image)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToListAsync());
}
```

In .cshtml

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item.ProductImages.FirstOrDefault()?.Image.FileId.ToString() ?? "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually just updated my query above as pasted the wrong thing above. However, I also tried your query and still get the same problem - Image is null.

ProductImages is fine - @item.ProductImages has multiple records, it's just they don't seem to be linked to Images hence the Image part is null. I'm not clear whether it's my query that needs to change or the Models?

Comment: Try to remove Take. If EF returns no records. Analyse SQL

Comment: Removing the Take doesn't resolve it unfortunately. I'm not sure how to analyse the underlying SQL on it though feels the issues should be in either my models or my controller.

Comment: Analyse returned data in controller. You have debugger.

Comment: I can see the returned data by debugging in the View. ProductImages has values. The Image entities for each ProductImage are null.

I presumed by analyse SQL you meant try and view the SQL queries as opposed to debugging and looking at what gets returned.

Comment: OMG, you just need `ThenInclude`. Updated answer.

Comment: Yes! ThenInclude was what I needed and now works. Thanks